# Javascript (jQuery) Syntax on button click action

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following Javascript:

```
var form = $(formArray[i]);
var formAction = form.attr("action");
var button = form.find("input:submit");
button.click(function (formAction, form) {
  return function () {
    var formAjaxAction = formAction.replace(originalString, ajaxString);
    ajaxPostHandler(formAjaxAction, onSuccessFunc, function () {
      errorHandler(errorMsg, widget);
    }, widget, "internalAjaxQueue", false, form);
    return false;
  };
}(formAction, form));
```

What does the final line do? Invoke the action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works like this:

```
function (formAction, form) {
  return function () {
    var formAjaxAction = formAction.replace(originalString, ajaxString);
    ajaxPostHandler(formAjaxAction, onSuccessFunc, function () {
      errorHandler(errorMsg, widget);
    }, widget, "internalAjaxQueue", false, form);
    return false;
  };
}
```

defines a function (obviously) but inside:

```
{function(...) ... }
```

it is scoped not to be visible outside that context. That function returns an anonymous function.

```
(function(...) ... }(formAction, form)
```

calls that function with those two arguments and:

```
button.click(...);
```

assigns that anonymous function to be a click event handler for the button.

It's a fairly obfuscated way to write what it's doing.

Comment: @Ben Aston.  If you find an answer particularly correct, you can mark it as such.

Answer (score 3):

This code defines a function that takes two parameters `function (formAction, form)` and returns a click handler.  `return function() { ... };`.

It then calls the function with the two parameters (the last line) and passes the function that it returns to jQuery's `click` function.

The reason to do it this way is that if you subsequently assign something else to the `form` or `formAction` variables, the handler will not be affected.